# How to add new DAGs to Airflow?

Tags: python, airflow

I have defined a DAG in a file called `tutorial_2.py` (actually a copy of the `tutorial.py` provided in the `airflow` tutorial, except with the `dag_id` changed to `tutorial_2`).

When I look inside my default, unmodified `airflow.cfg` (located in `~/airflow`), I see that `dags_folder` is set to `/home/alex/airflow/dags`.

I do `cd /home/alex/airflow; mkdir dags; cd dags; cp [...]/tutorial_2.py tutorial_2.py`. Now I have a `dags` folder matching the path set in `airflow.cfg` , containing the `tutorial_2.py` file I created earlier.

However, when I run `airflow list_dags`, I only get the names corresponding with the default, tutorial DAGs.

I would like to have `tutorial_2` show up in my DAG list, so that I can begin interacting with. Neither `python tutorial_2.py` nor `airflow resetdb` have caused it to appear in the list.

How do I remedy this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think the reason for this is because you haven't exported `AIRFLOW_HOME`.
Try doing:
`AIRFLOW_HOME="/home/alex/airflow/dags" airflow list_dags`.
If that's not working than do two steps

`export AIRFLOW_HOME="/home/alex/airflow/dags"
airflow list_dags`

I believe this should work. Give it a go?

Comment: This ought to be the right answer, with the caveat that you *may* need to check and correct the `airflow_home` and `dags_folder` variables in `airflow.cfg` as well. I am still unclear on why three different variables are necessary. cf. [here](https://gitter.im/apache/incubator-airflow?at=59581e6c6ae41d5d33a61aae).

Answer (score 7):

In my understanding, `AIRFLOW_HOME` should link to the directory where `airflow.cfg` is stored. Then, `airflow.cfg` can apply and set the dag directory to the value you put in it.

The important point is : `airflow.cfg` is useless if your `AIRFLOW_HOME` is not set

Comment: Exactly what Pierre said.^

Answer (score 6):

I might be using the latest airflow, the command has changed. What works for me is:

- `export AIRFLOW_HOME="~/airflow"`
- Then run `airflow dags list`

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you might have two airflow configs existing in your directories, so check for /root/airflow/dags and if yes you require to change the dags_folder path in both airflow.cfg s